# Identity cards number validation

Tags: c#, validation

I want to validate National identity card number for my small application.

```
There are only 9 digits
there is a letter at the end 'x' or 'v' (both capital and simple letters)
3rd digit can not be equal to 4 or 9
```

How can I validate this  using visual studio 2010? can I use regular expression to validate this?

Comment: As for regex, check this [link](http://myregexp.com/) for an online regex editor

Comment: Would an ID like "ABC123456789X" be a valid ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that without REGEX like:

```
string str = "124456789X";
if ((str.Count(char.IsDigit) == 9) && // only 9 digits
    (str.EndsWith("X", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
     || str.EndsWith("V", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && //a letter at the end 'x' or 'v'
    (str[2] != '4' && str[2] != '9')) //3rd digit can not be equal to 4 or 9
{
    //Valid

}
else
{
    //invalid
}
```

Comment: Agree but you should correct the -> 3rd digit cannot be equal to 4 or 9

Comment: The OP's question is unclear, and doesn't specify if there can be non-digits; I would assume not. Right now, the code you've given admits an ID like "ABC123456789V", which is unlikely to be a valid ID.

Comment: @dlev, The code above fullfills the OP requirement I think, since the answer has been accepted.

Comment: @Habib it should be `str.EndsWith("X", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` or use `ToUpper`

Answer (score 4):

**Srilanka NIC validation** - javascript

Old NIC format - ex : '641042757V'

```
/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/
```

New NIC format - ex : '196410402757'
(8th digit must be 0)

```
/^[0-9]{7}[0][0-9]{4}$/
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
 if ((ID.Count(char.IsDigit) == 9) && (ID.EndsWith("X") || ID.EndsWith("V")) && 
    (ID[2] != '4' && ID[2] != '9'))) 
                {
                    //Valid

                }
                else
                {
                    //invalid
                }
```

Comment: Did you copy/past Habib's answer?

Comment: no,i cant comment on others answers so i corrected it because third condition is wrong in habib's ans

Comment: @Anuj, it should be `&&` not `||` I think

Comment: actually you can edit @Habib 's answer only that it needs approval before it will be reflected on the original post.

Comment: ok @JW i got it,thanks for your suggesstion,next time i will surely do

Answer (score 1):

I'll guide you through building a regex for this but I won't actually do it for you.
Start with a blank regex:

```
-------------
```

You want 'X' or 'V' at the end

```
------(X or V)
```

Two digits at the front

```
(2 digits)--------(X or V)
```

a non 4 or 9 digit

```
(2 digits)(digit not 4 or 9)-----(X or V)
```

6 more digits

```
(2 digits)(digit not 4 or 9)(6 digits)(X or V)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**Sri Lankan NIC Validation**
```

```
$("input[name='number']").on('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    //alert(key);
    if (!([8, 9, 13, 27, 46, 110, 190,17, 88, 89].indexOf(key) !== -1 ||
            (key == 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
            (key >= 48 && key <= 57 && !(e.shiftKey || e.altKey)) ||
            (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
        )) e.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sriankan NIC Validation - JavaScript Regular Expressions(ECMAScripts)

Older NIC Format - ex: '952521381V'

1. Contain 9 Digits and 1 letter
2. 3rd digit not equal to '4' and '9'
3. After 9 digits, contain v or x

   ^\d{2}(?:[0-35-8]\d\d(?<!(?:000|500|36[7-9]|3[7-9]\d|86[7-9]|8[7-9]\d)))\d{4}(?:[vVxX])$

New NIC Format - ex: '199525201381'

1. Contain 9 Digits
2. 5th digit not equal to '4' and '9'
3. 8th digit equal to '0'
4. Only digits don't contain letters

   ^(?:19|20)?\d{2}(?:[0-35-8]\d\d(?<!(?:000|500|36[7-9]|3[7-9]\d|86[7-9]|8[7-9]\d)))[0]\d?\d{4}$

- For better explanation test the regular expressions in regex101.com

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Recently there two types of NIC number patterns. New NIC has just only 12 digit number combinations only, Old NIC has 9 digit number with X, V or x, v combination. Therefore, We have to check each and every NIC pattern separately. Here I have added separate logics for new NIC validation and OLD NIC validations.

for Old NIC Validation

```
public static bool validateNICOld(String nic) {
    int length = nic.length();
    if ((length != 10)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        char lastChar = nic.charAt((length - 1));
        String lastCharacter = String.valueOf(lastChar);
        if ((lastCharacter.equalsIgnoreCase("v") || lastCharacter.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))) {
            String number = nic.substring(0, (length - 1));
            Log.d("NUmber", number);
            return !number.trim().matches("/^[0-9]{9}/");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; (i
                    < (length - 2)); i++) {
                char currentChar = nic.charAt(i);
                if (((currentChar < '0') || ('9' < currentChar))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For new NIC Validation

```
 public static bool validateNICNew(String nic) {
    int length = nic.length();
    if ((length != 12)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.d("NIC", nic);
        return !nic.trim().matches("/[0-9]{12}/");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sri Lankan nic we have basically their types of nic  Formats
those are,

1)Format - ex: '952521381V'

2)Format - ex: '952521381X'

3)Format - ex: '199525201381'

for that, we can write to validate one and two  format
with this regex pattern

```
 \d{9}[vVxX]$)
```

for the third  format, we can use the below format

```
(^\d{12}$
```

now just simply combined it using OR logic gate

```
 public static bool Validate(string input)
{
    string pattern = @"(^\d{9}[vVxX]$)|(^\d{12}$)";
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
}
```

enjoy