# I need to validate NIC in focus lost event

Tags: java

I need to validate NIC in focus lost event.I used this code. even though i gave a correct NIC it's not working for all the situations it prints Invalid NIC message.
Can anyone say if there is something wrong in the code & tell me guidelines to where to correct in the code.

```
if(!(txtNic.getText().matches("/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/")))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid NIC ");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example NIC texts, both a few that work and a few that don't?

Comment: 927173024v this is a valid nic, even though i type this in the text box it shows "Invalid NIC" message. so how can i correct that above code to get correct result.

Comment: Are you sure you are evaluating the correct text? Have you debug that? Maybe the txtNic is the one that has wrong values and you THINK it is evaluating the correct text. Unclear without looking at the rest of the code.

Comment: **Check this link** [Srilanka NIC validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46822183/6523041)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the surrounding slashes in your regex:

```
if(!(txtNic.getText().trim().matches("^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$")))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid NIC ");
}
```

Should work. I've also added .trim() to make sure we're not putting in any whitespace that might get in there.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help, It worked as you've mentioned here.It was really helpful for me to correct my code. :-) :-)

Comment: No problem, don't forget to upvote any answers you found useful :)

Answer (score 2):

One of the pratfalls of `regex` is not understanding its pattern syntax ([Java Pattern Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

Let's breakdown the pattern you used:

```
"/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/"
```

- `/^` - Literal String
- `[0-9]{9}` - Character class of digits 0-9 repeated 9 times
- `[vVxX]` - Character class of characters v, V, x, & X
- `$/` - Literal String

So does 927173024v match that pattern? No it doesn't.  It doesn't begin with `"/^"` and it doesn't end with `"$/"`

As @TomElliot answer illustrates, you don't want the forward slashes in your pattern:

```
"^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$"
```

Now we have a break down of:

- `^` - Indicates the beginning of a line
- `[0-9]{9}` - Character class of digits 0-9 repeated 9 times
- `[vVxX]` - Character class of characters v, V, x, & X
- `$` - Indicates the end of a line.

Now 927173024v matches the pattern and would be flagged as valid.

### Alternative

Depending on the load of data you'd be validating, "sometimes" manual checks are, easier to understand and can perform faster than regex (More code does not mean slower performance).

Your regex pattern contains these rules:

- Must be 10 characters in length
- First 9 characters must be digits
- Last character must be a v, V, x, OR X

A custom method that validates using those rule "CAN" be easier to understand and "IS" faster `regex`.  In this scenario, it seems it wouldn't matter one way or the other as to how to validate the NIC, but here's a sample method that would validate it.

```
public static boolean validateNIC(String nic) {
    // Check if length is 10
    int length = nic.length();
    if (length != 10) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check last character for v, V, x, or X
    char lastChar = nic.charAt(length - 1);
    if (lastChar != 'v' || lastChar != 'V' || 
        lastChar != 'x' || lastChar != 'X') {
        return false;
    }

    // Check first 9 characters are digits
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 2; i++) {
        char currentChar = nic.charAt(i);
        if (currentChar < '0' || '9' < currentChar) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help, I understood my unclear point from your explanation . :-) :-)

Answer (score 2):

There two types of NIC numbers
New NIC has just only 12 digit number combinations only, Old NIC has 9 digit number with X, V or x, v combination.
Therefore it has to be checked all the types separately.

for Old NIC Validation

```
public static boolean validateNICOld(String nic) {
    int length = nic.length();
    if (length != 10) {
        return false;
    } else {
        char lastChar = nic.charAt(length - 1);
        String lastCharacter = String.valueOf(lastChar);
        if (lastCharacter.equalsIgnoreCase("v") || lastCharacter.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            String number = nic.substring(0, length - 1);
            Log.d("NUmber", number);
            if (!number.trim().matches("/^[0-9]{9}/")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 2; i++) {
                char currentChar = nic.charAt(i);
                if (currentChar < '0' || '9' < currentChar) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

for New NIC Validation

```
public static boolean validateNICNew(String nic) {
    int length = nic.length();
    if (length != 12) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.d("NIC", nic);
        if (!nic.trim().matches("/[0-9]{12}/")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
public class NICController {

@FXML
private TextField txtTele;

@FXML
private void clickValidation(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if (isValidNIC(txtTele.getText())) {
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Valid Nic", ButtonType.OK).showAndWait();
        txtTele.clear();
        txtTele.requestFocus();
    } else {
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Invalid NIC", ButtonType.OK).showAndWait();
        txtTele.requestFocus();
    }
}

private boolean isValidNIC(String input) {
    return input.matches("\\d{9}[Vv]");
}
```

}